# How to install Prisma migrations in a new environment

Tags: node.js, database, nestjs, prisma

I have been working in a little project of mine with prisma and nestJS, but now i want to move the dev environment to another PC, my source code have all prisma migrations.
How can I install all or at least the last migration to my new database in this other environment?
The database I am working on id Maria DB.

For example, I moved all the source code from my current PC to other, and I want to do something like:
$ prisma push migration
And now my new DB has all the tables from my last migration.

Answer (score -1):

You will want to follow the development workflow with prisma migrate. See this [documentation link](https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/database/developing-with-prisma-migrate). In a development environment, you use the `migrate dev` command to create an apply migrations